# Setup mail on unix, to send logs to gmail

Tags: unix, email, gmail, logging

I'm using logwatch to send email logs, but I'm having a hard time understanding how to set up a simple MTA to actually send them to my gmail. Most information I've found is on creating a full blown two-way mail client ([e.g.](https://wiki.debian.org/GmailAndExim4)), but I only need a way to send a log to one gmail.

What is the simplest way to send an email to gmail (no other functionality required)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you install exim, for example (debian / ubuntu):

```
aptitude install exim4
```

when in the setup dialog (you can relaunch it with `dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config`), you set:

- internet site (send mail directly)
- mail name = (you need a domain name there)
- listen on connection: 127.0.0.1, that way you don't accept or relay mail
- no relay
- minimal DNS = no
- format = mbox (for example)
- configuration in only 1 file
- root and postmaster recipient = root

You get a running configuration in 5-10 minutes max.

Comment: Works like a charm ;) I created a filter for it in gmail, specifying to label it and not mark as spam. Gmail seems to still give a warning, but no big deal.